# regex lookahead or clauses

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need an or clause in my lookahead:

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]{2,50}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9'\s]+$/m
```

Here, I require an uppercase,lowercase, and a number with my lookahead.

What I need is a lookahead that requires either an uppercase and a lowercase, a second clause with a lowercase, or a third clause with just a number.

Here is some data:

- 224
- Jonscompany
- jonscompany

Comment: Can you show some input data?

Comment: @hek2mgl done. added test data

Comment: I can't see how the test data which you've posted is related to the suggested regex

Comment: 224 fails because the lookahead requires a lowecase,uppercase,and number and it only contains a number. Jonscompany fails because there is no number and jonscompany fails because there is no number or uppercase.

Comment: Please add some examples that must match and some that don't match.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE if you look at the previous comment it explains the failing test data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not I well understand your needs, but is that OK?

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]{2,50}$)(?=.*(?:[A-Za-z]|\d))[a-zA-Z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9'\s]+$/m
```

May this would suffice:

```
/^(?:\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)$/
```

**According to comment:**

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9'\s]{2,50}$)(?=.*(?:[A-Za-z]|\d))[a-zA-Z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9'\s]+$/m
```

**Explanation:**

```
/
^                           : Start of string
(?=[A-Za-z0-9'\s]{2,50}$)   : lookahead, from 2 up to 50 characters that are in the class
(?=.*(?:[A-Za-z]|\d))       : lookahead, there is at least one letter or one digit
[a-zA-Z0-9]+                : one or more alphanum
[A-Za-z0-9'\s]+             : one or more alphanum or quote or space
$                           : end of string
/m
```

Comment: are these lookaheads OR clauses?

Comment: for some reason if the spaces (\s) is not in the lookahead it does not work.

Comment: also, can you please break down both regexes so i can understand each part and the difference between them

Comment: @jkushner: Sure, if you want to allow spaces, you have to put it in the character class.

Comment: Yes but doesn't putting it in a look ahead mean that it requires a space. WHy isn't it the space declaration at the end sufficient?